# Firefox fails to load CSS files on HTTPS

Tags: html, css, firefox, ssl

You can see my problem here:
https://www.rekuperatory.pl/ssltest/

When you open this site with **Firefox** it fails to load CSS. The thing is, CSS is loaded correctly in Chrome, IE and Opera. Also inline styles are read by FF correctly.

There's no issue when visiting the site via HTTP:
http://www.rekuperatory.pl/ssltest/ - it loads just fine on every browser including Firefox.

The problem is **only with Firefox, only via HTTPS and only with CSS in a separate file.**

I've contacted hosting provider and they're saying, that everything is all right with SSL Certificate and the problem must be in linking CSS file. But I don't think that's true. Just see the code:

```css
h1{
  color: #2387ff;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>
    This should be blue and centered
</h1>

<div class="hide">CSS NOT LOADED* <br/> <small>*This DIV has "display: none" rule</small>
</div>

<h2 style="  color: #499249; text-align: center; background-color: #e6ffe3;">
    Header with inline style.
</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more than likely due to the incorrect headers on the response of the request for `style.css`

> https://www.rekuperatory.pl/ssltest/style.css was not loaded because
>   its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

Note that when you visit the `http://` url the server is correctly responding with `Content-Type: text/css`, however on the `https://` url it responds with `Content-Type: text/html`.

Comment: Indeed... Funny thing is Firebug doesn't throw this error. It only seen in bundled developer tools. That's why I did not see it. Do you know how can I fix this so the server returns correct type?

Comment: You would have to ensure that your server has correct settings for the MIME types you are having issues with, this would depend on what web server you are using to serve content.  I suggest this would be more successful in a new question specifically for this issue.

Comment: As it turns out, it was caused by .htaccess entry responsible for handling browser cache. Everything works great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people found complex solutions. In my case I just needed to delete cache files and cookies (later one is mostly omitted in refreshing). Not only in the browser but also in your site if you use cache optimization.